# Why can't I use my token to log into my bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to log in to my discord bot but it only works using **discord.js v12**. I also have a config file where I stored my token so I could use `config.token`, but it shows **invalid**.

When I use v13 none works. Even when I use the actual token it shows **invalid** and when I use `config.token` it shows invalid too. Here is the code:

```js
console.clear();
    
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./Data/config.json");   
const intents = new Discord.Intents(32767);  
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents });
  
client.on("ready", () => console.log("Bot is online!"));
    
client.on("messageCreate", message => {

   if(message.content == "hello") message.reply("Hello!");
    
});
    
client.login("token");
```

The bot also doesn't reply back too.
This is my config file.

```json
{
   "token": "token",
   "prefix": "!"
}
```

Comment: Can you please send us the error you get in console?

Comment: What are the intents your client has?

Comment: Could you please add also smth like `client.on('error', console.error)` to see actual error

Comment: Start by picking a version and stick to it, preferably the latest (v13)

Comment: Try resetting your token in discord developer portal, and copy paste it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to log in using a string, to use the token variable from your config, use `client.login(config.token)`, without quotes around it. This gets the `config` variable, then the `token` variable inside it, or `config.token`.

Your code would look something like this:

```
console.clear();
    
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./Data/config.json");   
const intents = new Discord.Intents(32767);  
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents });
  
client.on("ready", () => console.log("Bot is online!"));
    
client.on("messageCreate", message => {

   if(message.content == "hello") message.reply("Hello!");
    
});
    
client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: Apparently i didn't see that before and now i feel like total buffoon, sorry about that